# i want to add html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so here i get this jquery sliding side menu plugin,i want to add span glyphicon on the javascript code,but it turns to string,can anyone help me?

this is the plugin code,it's entirely javascript,that's why it's so hard to edit it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Creating the master menu (SideMenu)
    sideMenu = new SideMenu([
        new SMLabelItem("The First Item Added!")
    ], {
        overlay: true
    });


    // Adding items with events ("Share")
    sideMenu.addItem(new SMSubMenuItem("Share", [
        new SMButtonItem("Facebook", function() {
            window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(location));
        }, "fb"),
        new SMButtonItem("Twitter", function() {
            window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=SideMenu.js&url=' + encodeURIComponent(location));
        }, "tw"),
        new SMButtonItem("Google+", function() {
            window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?hl=es-419&url=' + encodeURIComponent(location));
        }, "gp"),
        new SMButtonItem("Pinterest", function() {
            alert("Pinterest Share");
        }, "pin")
    ]));



    // Adding mix items ("Animals")
    sideMenu.addItem(new SMSubMenuItem("Animals", [
        new SMLinkItem("Bunny", "https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=Bunny"),
        new SMLinkItem("Tiger", "https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=Tiger"),
        new SMLinkItem("Dog", "https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=Dog"),
        new SMLinkItem("Cat", "https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=Cat", "_blank"),
        new SMSubMenuItem("Birds", [
            new SMLinkItem("Eagle", "https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=eagle"),
            new SMLabelItem("Hawk"),
            new SMLabelItem("Tucan"),
            new SMButtonItem("Parrot", function() {
                alert("Hello World!");
            }),
            new SMLabelItem("Chicken"),
            new SMLabelItem("Duck")
        ]),
        new SMLabelItem("Pig"),
        new SMLinkItem("Crocodile", "https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=Crocodile")
    ]));


    // Adding simple label items
    sideMenu.addItem(new SMSubMenuItem("Continents", [
        new SMLinkItem("Europe","https://www.google.com.pe/?#q=Crocodile"),
        new SMLabelItem("Asia"),
        new SMLabelItem("Africa"),
        new SMSubMenuItem("North America", [
            new SMLabelItem("Canada"),
            new SMLabelItem("Mexico"),
            new SMLabelItem("United States")
        ]),
        new SMLabelItem("Center America"),
        new SMSubMenuItem("South America", [
            new SMLabelItem("Argentina"),
            new SMLabelItem("Bolivia"),
            new SMLabelItem("Brasil"),
            new SMLabelItem("Colombia"),
            new SMLabelItem("Chile"),
            new SMLabelItem("Ecuador"),
            new SMLabelItem("Paraguay"),
            new SMSubMenuItem("Perú", [
                new SMLabelItem("Lima"),
                new SMLabelItem("Trujillo"),
                new SMLabelItem("Loreto"),
                new SMLabelItem("Cuzco"),
                new SMLabelItem("Puno"),
                new SMLabelItem("Cajamarca"),
                new SMLabelItem("etc..")
            ]),
            new SMLabelItem("Uruguay")
        ]),
        new SMLabelItem("Oceanía"),
        new SMLabelItem("Antartida")
    ]));


    // Adding new item
    sideMenu.addItem(
        new SMButtonItem("Download File", function() {
            alert("Go Download File!");
        })
    );



    // Adding new item
    sideMenu.addItem(
        new SMButtonItem("Close", function() {
            sideMenu.close();
        })
    );



    // CUSTOM ITEM
    // This is a custom item example
    // all created custom items extend from SMItem Class.

    SMUserAccountItem = (function(name, src) {
        SMItem.call(this); // Call SMItem constructor
        // this._el is jQuery item object that works how wrapper
        $(this.el).addClass('sm-item-useraccount')
            .append(
                this.photo = $('<img/>')
                .addClass('sm-useraccount-photo')
                .attr({
                    src: src
                }).get(0)
            )
            .append(
                this.name = $('<div/>')
                .addClass('sm-useraccount-name')
                .text(name).get(0)
            );
    });



    // Finally add SideMenu object to DOM tree target.
    $(function() {
        sideMenu.appendTo(document.getElementById('menu'));
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="menu" class="sm-main"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Hope this will work for you;

```
$('<button />', {
```

class: 'btn btn-default',
  type: 'button',
  id: 'test1',
  html: ''
});

Comment: wait2 i am still confuse,where i put that ? sorry but i am still kind a new in javascript or jquery

Comment: in your javascript file.

Comment: yes obviously,but specificly,where ? do i have to make smlabel object or put that inside  the object or do turn it into variables,where is the specificly place to put that ?